# Tableau - Would like to get last day stock position if user selected multiple dates

Tags: indexing, formula, tableau-api

Show Stock on hand value of last day, if user has selected multiple dates
Just last day stock e.g. if user has selected 21st Sept, 22nd Sept and 23rd September it should display Stock on hand and stock on hand Value for 23rd of September. Similarly, whatever dates user will select I want to show last day of Stock position. I have tried maximum date but it selects maximum date from whole dataset. Dataset contains last 15 days of data.
I am using tableau desktop 2020.2.5 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Do the following steps-
Steps-1: Add a calcF as

```
INDEX()
```

step-2: Add prod_id, date, and calcF to rows and SOH also

step-3: For calcF --> right click --> compute using `Date`  --> right click again --> Edit table calculation --> Sort Order --> set descending by max of date.  (

[image: screenshot]

step-4: add calcF to filter additionally with your date column... Select only `1` from the values.  you'll get the desired view.

[image: screenshot]

I have used the following data-

```
product_id,date,soh
1,01-01-2020,22
1,02-01-2020,26
1,03-01-2020,33
1,04-01-2020,36
2,01-01-2020,35
2,02-01-2020,26
2,03-01-2020,25
2,04-01-2020,26
3,01-01-2020,36
3,02-01-2020,35
3,03-01-2020,55
3,04-01-2020,56
```

.twbx file shared here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ko_LG2qAlYqmPdM-PcVBx6SmH6NXtym6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you Anil for your response. Could you please share your .twbx file here? i will go through that for my understanding and help others to get better understanding

Comment: @user3061338 I will share it.

Comment: @user3061338, I have shared .twbx file link in answer.  Please acknowledge if it serves the purpose

Comment: THank you, yes this makes sense. Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

Set your filter to context so the Level Of Detail calc will reflect it.

```
{max([date_field])}
```

Comment: Thank you Bernardo, but user can select 1 day as well, i have created one calculated field called selected days, where i am counting distinct dates in dataset. I want if selected day is greater than equal to 1 than select maximum date from selections. how can i do that

Comment: You are still unclear.  Please illustrate your desired output with an example dataset

Comment: For example, does your data have a record per product per day showing the stock on hand for that product at the end of that day? Or does your data only record changes in stock, such as deliveries or sales with the net change? are there records for every day? or only records when there is a change?

Comment: Hi Alex and Anil, Each product have SOH on daily basis. I have inventory date and Stock  on hand value and Product ID three columns. If user Selects multiple dates I do not want to aggregate SOH value for each product I want to show latest Stock in Hand from user selection.

Comment: @user3061338 see the solution now, and please check and tell me whether it works